# How can I extract Web Controls from a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a set of `TextBox`es and a set of `DropDownList`s. When you choose a value from the `DropDownList` it changes the background color of the corresponding `TextBox`.

To make this easier, I tried to create a `Dictionary<TextBox, DropDownList>`, but the `Key` property is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` and the `Value` property is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`, instead of `TextBox1` and `DropDownList1`.

How should I iterate through the `Dictionary` to set the `TextBox` and `DropDownList` values properly?

```
namespace TextBoxColorPicker
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            get_box_colors();
        }

        protected void get_box_colors()
        {
            var textbox_dict = new Dictionary<TextBox, DropDownList>();

            textbox_dict.Add(TextBox1,DropDownList1);
            textbox_dict.Add(TextBox2,DropDownList2);
            textbox_dict.Add(TextBox3, DropDownList3);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBox, DropDownList> entry in textbox_dict)
            {
                TextBox txtbox = entry.Key;
                DropDownList list = entry.Value;

                Label1.Text = txtbox.ToString();
                Label2.Text = list.ToString();

                if (list.SelectedValue == "R")
                {
                    txtbox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else if (list.SelectedValue == "A")
                {
                    txtbox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
                }
                else if (list.SelectedValue == "G")
                {
                    txtbox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtbox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally this isn't really about dictionaries at all - it's about what a call to `ToString()` on a `TextBox` or `DropDownList` will return... and it sounds like it's inheriting the implementation from `System.Object` which just returns the type name.

It's unclear what you're really trying to do, but it sounds like you want the `ID` property instead of `ToString()`:

```
Label1.Text = txtbox.ID;
Label2.Text = list.ID;
```

Personally I probably wouldn't want the IDs to be part of the UI as such, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

These lines seem to be the issue:

```
Label1.Text = txtbox.ToString();
Label2.Text = list.ToString();
```

try this (if you're needing the values, otherwise refer to Jon Skeet's answer)

```
Label1.Text = txtbox.Text;
Label2.Text = list.SelectedValue;
```